# Tableau Fixed Calculation Summing too much data

Tags: tableau-api

I have volume data for specific customers. The customer names come from salesforce and the volume comes from another table. When I add each in tableau, i get a nice table that seems to be working.

[image]

We can see that there are 19 values ~500 My ultimate goal is to sum these based upon filters.

A way i discovered that i can do that is to use the syntax

`{ FIXED [Account Id]: count([Volume]) }`

But when i do that,

I get

[image]

When I change my function to count([volume]) i get a count of all joined rows ~250k

My question is how do i make this respect indivudal entries in the database and not all the joined values? If there was a way to do the sum for distinct timestamps in another field this would also work? Any other advice would be helpful from you tableau experts.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to sum? The fixed calculation is summing volume by account ID. Remove the LOD calculation if you are just trying to sum by the view of the viz.

Comment: Literally all i want is a sum of the view we see. those 19 values

Comment: My ultimate goal is to be able to get a sum of the year. I am just trying to practice aggregating the sum, but it is giving me issues.

Comment: I think i got it. 

In the table of the database that i was trying to calculate there were 20 rows that needed to be calculated. When the data was joined in SF, it duplicated the rows. 


The trick here was to do the sum of the max for each primary key



SUM({ FIXED    [Endts], [Pk], [Name1] : MAX([Volume]) })

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it. In the table of the database that i was trying to calculate there were 20 rows that needed to be calculated. When the data was joined in SF, it duplicated the rows. The trick here was to do the sum of the max for each primary key

`SUM({ FIXED [Pk], [Name1] : MAX([Volume]) })`